# Pattern for multiple model components

Tags: libgdx, fbx, 3d-model

I am using libgdx for loading my 3D Model. In my game the player should be able to use i.e. other helmets, than the default one.

With *.fbx I am able to load ONE model with ONE skeleton that contains the animation. What if I want add a helmet to the player now?

Two solutions?!

- All components (basemodel+helmet+whatever) of the character itself are seperate models with the same skeleton and the same animations
- One model (fbx/g3d*) contains all possible components and they get enabled/disabled when they are needed.

Is there a better pattern? How do you do that?